# JavaScript: Calculate Window Height on Mobile

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, safari, window

How can I calculate the window height on mobile devices in order to see if controls are visible after scrolling?

[image]

```
window.innerHeight
```

only gives me the size of the visible area. Desktop browsers should return the same value as **window.innerHeight** as no controls are visible over the page.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know. You mayby already tried this. But window.outerHeight mayby works?

Link i got is from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerHeight

i hope it helps

Comment: window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight will also return a value on desktop browsers so it's not useful in my case.